# I'm not sure how a JSON object loop works in this context

Tags: android, json

How does one get JSONobjects to update every 1.5 seconds for multiple text views?

?
A loop?

I could not find an answer based on my situation.

Here is my JSON https://api.wheretheiss.at/v1/satellites/25544

```
public class IsstatusActivity extends AppCompatActivity {







String longitSt;


JSONParser jsonparser = new JSONParser();
TextView latitude;
TextView longitude;


String lat;
String longit;


JSONObject jobj = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.isstatus);
    latitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Coordinates);


    new retrievedata().execute();

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.

    return true;
}


class retrievedata extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    public String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        jobj = jsonparser.makeHttpRequest("http://api.wheretheiss.at/v1/satellites/25544");

        // check your log for json response

        try {
            lat = "latitude: " + jobj.getString("latitude");
            longit = "longitude :" + jobj.getString("longitude");

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



            return lat;


    }

}








    protected void onPostExecute(String lat) {

        latitude.setText(lat);
         longit.setText(longitude);




    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the timer.

```
Timer timer = new Timer(true);
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
         // do something
     }
}, 0, 1500);
```